# What does entering of sex chromosomes to gametes mean during meiosis I?

Tags: homework, meiosis

I am reading [one answer about meiosis](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_male_meiosis_and_female_meiosis_for_humans):

> During meiosis I, the sex chromosomes separate and enter different
>   sperm or egg cells (gametes).

I assume that sex chromosomes refer here to homologous chromosomes that experience crossing-over after meiosis that is exchange of genetical information.

Meiosis I refers here to female meiosis I and to male meiosis I. 
In both cases, homologous chromosomes separate resulting in haploid cells after meiosis I.
*These homologous chromosomes enter sperm or egg cells* according to the writer, which I cannot understand, since the given chromosomes, now sister chromatids after meiosis I, do not enter physically anything, they just divide into haploid cells, gametes, after meiosis II.

**What is the meaning of the word "enter" in the given sentence?**

I am confused by the word "enter".
I am assuming that the word refers to enter something physically which is not the case in my opinion here.

Comment: After meiosis I, the resulting cells are haploid, not diploid, but they have 2n chromosomes.

Comment: @GerganaVandova So meiosis I is the stage where male (XY -> X and Y) and female (XX -> active X and inactive X). So the resulting cells are haploid.

Comment: So that mean that there is no halving of chromosomes anymore in meiosis II, since it is done in meiosis I. Cells are throughout meiosis I haploid, while haploid only after anaphase in meiosis I.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure anymore whether the inactivation of the female X chromosome happens right away from anaphase I.

Comment: X-inactivation occurs post-fertilization, only if fertilized by a X-carrying sperm. In meiosis I, HOMOLOGOUS chromosomes (meaning your mom and dad's copy of your genes) separate. In meiosis II, SISTER CHROMATIDS (i.e. copies of your mom's or your dad's chromosomes) separate.

Comment: @jp89 X-inactivation seems to happen in two places: at the end of meiosis I and then somewhere during meiosis II. - In the former case, there are two daughter cells. The other of the cells gain very little cytoplasm, while the other much. The other with very little cytoplasm will be the polar body.

Comment: And then finally the polar body from meiosis I divides to two new polar bodies while the secondary oocyte divides to ovum and one new polar body. So one ovum and three polar bodies. - Ok, the main question still unanswered. - Ok, I will do it, since the answer seems to be that "become" different sperm or egg cells.

Comment: @Masi You have some flaws in your logic here. The first polar body does not divide into more polar bodies. Once a polar body, always a polar body. At the end of female meiosis II, your total products is 2 polar bodies and 1 mature ovum.

Comment: @Masi And to address the question of X-inactivation, x-inactivation only occurs in diploid XX cells under regulation of the XIST gene from the non-inactivated X chromosome. When homologous chromosomes separate in meiosis I, x-inactivation cannot occur since the XIST gene product from either the paternal or maternal chromosome cannot act on the other X chromosome because they're simply not in the same cell anymore.

Comment: @jp89 Are you sure about polar bodies? - If so, then this must a mistake again in Wikipedia and in my lecture materials too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gray5.svg The picture suggests for instance that the primary polar body can divide again to two polar bodies.

Comment: @jp89 The thing does not seem to be so simple: "Sometimes the first polar body undergoes the second meiotic cell division." - Ok, but how that is possible? - The primary polar body is haploid. How can it divide again meiotically and be still haploid? - I would think that mitotic division is needed to have two more polar bodies from the primary polar body.

Comment: @Masi See here (http://www.uic.edu/classes/bms/bms655/lesson9.html), here (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10008/#A4696) and here (http://faculty.stcc.edu/AandP/AP/AP2pages/reprod/oogenesi.htm). There's also a great diagram in my medical genetics book but it's not on the internet.

Comment: @Masi Even if the first polar body divides, it still divides meiotically. It retains it's haploid nature because in meiosis II, sister chromatids separate rather than homologous chromosomes. It is separation of homologous chromosomes (in MI) that results in reduction of ploidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to now understand the sentence. I read the clause in other words:

> During meiosis I, the sex chromosomes of the gametogonia separate in
>   anaphase I and II and become eventually different sperm or egg cells
>   after cell differentiation and maturation: male spermiogenesis and
>   female maturation into ovum.

Female thing does not seem to have a special name for the maturation thing.
Female does not seem to have differentiation part at the last part similarly as male, since only one ovum is formed after the sequence of events. 
Sex chromosomes refer to your parents genotypes. [jg89]

Problem seems to be solved now.

I would not personally use the word "enter" in a such sequence. It is a shortcut. Better would be "enter eventually" or "enter after a sequence of events". I prefer explicity instead of implicity.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure whether the last female step has anything to do with differentiation. It seems that it just a maturation step, since there will only be one ovum, while 4 male spermatozoa where the differentiation makes sense. I will fix it. Please, reply if I am wrong.